# What to use to open an .mdf (SQL Database) file

Tags: sql-server, webmatrix

I was hoping to be able to open .mdf file. I am using WebMatrix, I can view the queries there. I can read the schema too. But how can I read the file without using WebMatrix. Its SQL Server file not the Comptact edition.

I have searched for web help (Through windows). But all in vain. I will prefer any link or any method to read the basic queries.

Comment: but `.sdf` _is_ a Compact database...

Comment: Sorry, file format is .mdf. It was my bad!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`.sdf` is, in fact, a Compact Database file (unless you've changed the extension which would be problematic). SQL Server would be `.mdf`.

#### SQL Server (`.mdf`)

You can attach the database to your local SQLEXPRESS instance and view it. An example of attaching it can be found on msdn: [How to: attach a Database File to SQL Server Express](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165673%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Essentially you're calling:

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE DATABASE [database_name] ON 
    ( FILENAME = N'C:\Path\To\<database name>.mdf' ),
    ( FILENAME = N'C:\Path\To\<database name>.ldf' )
    FOR ATTACH ;
GO
```

#### SQL Compact Edition (`.sdf`)

The best tool I've found to open them is [CompactView](http://sourceforge.net/projects/compactview/).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Sorry It was my bad. I have just edited the file name! Actually I am having two folders one is the folder for App_Data (The one that is in the documents) and the other in C:\. So it just slipped off my mind. Sorry

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan: No worried; Updated the answer for accommodate for `.mdf`. best thing to do is just attach it to your local SQLEXPRESS. (A walk-through can be found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhIr9Qf-oHw))

Comment: Sorry youtube is blocked here! :( Will try to Google it. Anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

SysTools SQL MDF Viewer can be used to view the table contents. I tried with the free trial version.

Comment: but it cant be used to get or copy something out of it